# ASP.Net Linq to Entities: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.- EntityConnectionStringBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, metadata

I have read through quite a few of the posts but this appears very useful but I'm not sure I understand how to implement this solution.  Am I supposed to put this code in every class that uses the entity model?  I've read through the Microsoft docs and I guess I'm just too new at this.

My entity model is in my DATALAYER which is a separate project.  I also have BUSINESSLOGIC AND UI layers.  From what I've been able to glean, it sounds like the problem is related to the fact that my entity model is in a different project.  Is that right?  Thanks in advance!

From another post **A better way to construct connection strings is with EntityConnectionStringBuilder:**

```
public static string GetSqlCeConnectionString(string fileName) 
{ 
    var csBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(); 

    csBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"; 
    csBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};", fileName); 

    csBuilder.Metadata = string.Format("res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.csdl|res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.ssdl|res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.msl",  
        typeof(YourObjectContextType).Assembly.FullName); 

    return csBuilder.ToString(); 
} 

public static string GetSqlConnectionString(string serverName, string databaseName) 
{ 
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder providerCs = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(); 

    providerCs.DataSource = serverName; 
    providerCs.InitialCatalog = databaseName; 
    providerCs.IntegratedSecurity = true; 

    var csBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(); 

    csBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient"; 
    csBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerCs.ToString(); 

    csBuilder.Metadata = string.Format("res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.csdl|res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.ssdl|res://{0}/YourEdmxFileName.msl", 
        typeof(YourObjectContextType).Assembly.FullName); 

    return csBuilder.ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you move connection details to your config files? Here is an article about [connection strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.connectionstring.aspx). And following the same examples as in the article, here is the initialization and use of the context:

```
using (EntityConnection connection =  EntityConnection("name=AdventureWorksEntities"))
{
    AdventureWorksEntities context = new AdventureWorksEntities(connection);
    context.AddObject("Customer", customer);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

EDIT: there is no need to repeat the connection building code in the calling clients. You should hide these details away from the callers. Here is example of the factory that returns new object context:

```
//app.config
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestEntities" connectionString="...." />
</connectionStrings>

//data entities
public partial class TestEntities : ObjectContext
{
    public TestEntities() : base("name=TestEntities", "TestEntities")
    {
        ...
    }
    ....
}

//factory in Data Access layer
public sealed class TestEntitiesFactory
{
    public static Func<TestEntities> GetNewTestEntitiesInstance { get; set; }

    static TestEntitiesFactory()
    {
        GetNewTestEntitiesInstance = TestEntitiesCreator.CreateTestEntities;
    }
}

public sealed class TestEntitiesDefaultCreator
{
    public static TestEntities CreateTestEntities()
    {
        TestEntities test = new TestEntities();

        //whatever initializations you need

        return test;
    }
}

//business layer
using (TestEntities ctx = TestEntitiesFactory.GetNewTestEntitiesInstance())
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  The code I pasted above is the portion preceding what you have posted.  It appears to me that I need all the preceding code before the USING function you have inserted.  My confusion is where all of this goes. Do I need to put this in every class that calls the entities?

Comment: I added an example how you can expose access to your entities.

Comment: @Susan, you don't have to use the factory and the creator of course. You can simply go with: using (TestEntities contex = new TestEntities()){}; As you can see, default constructor is using the connection string name that is specified in the app.config file.